# xcode/ios: How to pass data when programmatically launching modal view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller

Hi I am launching a view controller that exists in storyboard programmatically with following code (which although it works may not be quite right).  The view controller is a screen to edit  a detail view that originally descends from a tableview.  There is no segue available to me in storyboard--which is why I am launching it programmatically.

```
- (void) editView:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"pressed");
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
    IDEditVC *secondViewController =
    [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editvc"];
}
```

Question:

How do I pass the index path or row of the table so that I can draw in proper data for this record?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you instantiate `@"editvc"` twice?

Comment: you have instance of 'secondViewController', declare any property in .h file of IDEditVC say NSString *myString. And use it like secondViewController.myString = yourIndexPath

Comment: If you have a pointer to the new view controller (which you do, since you created it), you can send it any message you like, including messages to set whatever data it might need.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no segue available"? You can create a segue.

Comment: I removed two extraneous lines.  There is no segue in storyboard because for some reason I don't understand, the detail VC would not let me add an edit button to the navigation bar.  This is why I am programmatically creating edit button and launching edit view controller.  If there is a way to create a segue programmatically I don't know it.

Comment: I'm very confused and am assuming you're new to iOS development. You pass data to a logically instantiated viewController like any other object created in memory..... you assign a property value when instantiating the object. Unless you mean rigging delegate callbacks or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to define a property on the modal VC and assign the index path to it.

```
- (void)editView:(id)sender
{       
    IDEditVC *secondViewController = (IDEditVC *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editvc"];
    secondViewController.selectedIndexPath = yourIndexPath;
}
```

Where `selectedIndexPath` is a property that you've defined on `IDEditVC`
And `yourIndexPath` is the index path that you want to use to populate the `IDEditVC`

Are you having any issues getting to that index path? Do you save it somewhere?

Comment: I have it in the original table view controller prepareforsegue but it is a bit tricky as I am using core data.  There I have   
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                Items *item = [self.fetchedResultsController  destViewController.item=item;objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];  Then in detail view in viewDidLoad  I just use  self.itemLabel.text = self.item.name; where name is a property of the item entity and itemLabel is a property in the VC. So at this point the index path is sort of implicit.

Comment: Make property for Items in iDEditvc and after that pass value by making object second view controller.items = self.item